# Rails join table record creation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, join

If I have a HABTM join table called, `:inventory_items_shopping_lists`, how do I create and call records in this table? I do not have a join model. The two joined models are `:inventory_items` and `:shopping_lists`. I'd like to be able to have a user add `:inventory_items` to their `:shopping_lists`. Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**

Here are the relevant models and my goal:

```
class InventoryItem < ActiveRecord::Base

    belongs_to  :item, :foreign_key => :item_id
    belongs_to  :vendor
    has_many    :list_items
end

class ListItem < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to  :inventory_item, :foreign_key => :item_id
    belongs_to  :shopping_list
end

class ShoppingList < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :list_items
    belongs_to  :user, :foreign_key => :user_id
end
```

I'm attempting to have a `:user` add `:inventory_items` to a `:shopping_list` where they will become `:list_items`. `list_items` have almost identical attributes of `:inventory_items`, so I will likely just reference those attributes through association than by duplicating the attributes in the `:list_items` table. Thoughts or suggestions on this? I'm newish to RoR so I appreciate any feedback on any part of this plan. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah seems like you're on the right track. You can add `ListItem#created_at` to know when a user added an item to their shopping list, for instance. It looks like you have exactly what you need(?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how do I create and call records in this table?

You basically don't with a HABTM association type. If you want to store more state on the join  table than you will need to use a standard `has_many` (and maybe a `has_many :through`) so you can manipulate the underlying join model.

For this reason I have never been a fan of HABTM and in fact I have a handful of large Rails apps in production and I have never used HABTM myself.

Comment: Ah I see. I was starting to see some limitations of HABTM while researching this, you just confirmed my suspicions. If I do use a join model (let's call it `:list_item`), both :inventory_item and :list_item would have almost identical attributes. Is that wasteful, or just necessary duplication in order to achieve my goal? Thanks!

Comment: @settheline I don't really follow what you're goal is. Go to my profile and grab my email, send me an email with your inventory_items and shopping_lists definition and what you're trying to achieve with list_item

Comment: I couldn't find your email address from your profile, so I went ahead and posted the relevant models and my end goal in an edit. Thanks Cody.